# Allowing a client to upload an arbitrary file to a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension based signing application that uses openpgp.js to take an arbitrary document from a user's file system, allows them to attach a header file and then signs the hash of the composition.

I know how to implement the signing functionality, I'm just uncertain how to get a file from the user's file system into the extensions sandboxed storage. My goal would be for the user experience to be drag and drop (client drags file from desktop into a space in an html page managed by the extension). Any ideas?

Comment: For examples and documentation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications